# Index exception when using LIKE clause?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mariadb

I'm calling `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL)` on my server to enable any warnings and errors that may need fixing. Since `MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX` is inherited, PHP is also [reporting bad/no index use](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php#refsect1-mysqli-driver.report-mode-parameters).

I have set up my table properly, but still get the following exception when using a LIKE clause:

> mysqli_sql_exception: No index used in query/prepared statement (null)

However, when using `=` instead of `LIKE`, I no longer get this error.

Is this fixable?

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
    `ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    INDEX `Title` (`Title`)
);
```

And this is the code I'm testing on my server:

```
$db = mysqli_connect($Host, $User, $Pass, $Database);

$Stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($db);

// This works
mysqli_stmt_prepare($Stmt, 'SELECT ID FROM articles WHERE Title = ?');
$Title = 'test';
// This doesn't work
mysqli_stmt_prepare($Stmt, 'SELECT ID FROM articles WHERE Title LIKE ?');
$Title = '%test%';

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($Stmt, 's', $Title);
mysqli_stmt_execute($Stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($Stmt, $ID);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($Stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($Stmt);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a normal behavior.

mysql indexes work by indexing N characters starting from the left of the value.

As a consequence, your index is not used when you do :

```
WHERE Title LIKE '%Test%'
```

This is because the string to match starts with a wildcard, which represents a variable number of characters.

The index will be used if you do :

```
WHERE Title LIKE 'Test%'
```

Or of course :

```
WHERE Title = 'Test'
```

Comment: In most situations, `Title LIKE 'Test'` (no wildcard) is optimized to `Title = 'Test'`.